# What is the theory that there is more than one "Satan" called, and what is its basis?

Tags: terminology, satan

I'm remembering back to a conversation that I had with an individual who was adamant about the fact that Satan was a made up Angel. That instead of Satan being a singular object, satan was actually the term for an angel.

He was claiming that there is more then one satan in existence and they did the bidding of God.

**If you know what this theory is called or if there is any evidence being it, please let me know.**

> **Matthew 12:26** NKJV
>
> If Satan casts out Satan, he is divided against himself. How then will
>   his kingdom stand?

Comment: [Gnosticism](http://www.mountain-goats.com/forums/read.php?2,101036,101046), maybe?

Comment: The Hebrew **הַשָׂטָן** (Satan) literally means *adversary*.

Comment: Interesting. However, the Greek interlinear says "kai ei ho satanas ton satanan" so there seems to be a slight difference, albeit I have no clue how significant it is. http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/NTpdf/mat12.pdf

Comment: @felideon That is fascinating!  Is it possible that when they spoke Greek they were using the Hebrew word in it's place (like how English borrows *many* words from other languages)?  I wonder if that came from the culture of reading the Old Testament Hebrew regularly.  Nice find!!

Comment: @felideon. You might want to ask at Linguistics to be sure, but I suspect that the difference between *satanas* and *satanan* is purely grammatical: one is the subject of the verb and the other is the object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Hebrew word *satan* means "accuser" or "adversary". It can be used in a general sense rather than as a proper noun. This does not mean that *all* occurrences of the word refer to a generic accuser. For example, Luke 10:18,

> I saw Satan fall like lightning from heaven,

is clearly referring to a specific individual. But in 1 Kings 11:14,

> Then the Lord raised up against Solomon an adversary, Hadad the Edomite, from the royal line of Edom,

the English "adversary" is translating Hebrew "satan". Clearly Hadad is not the actual devil.

In the book of Job, "Satan" appears in heaven and is instructed by God to torment Job. This matches the idea that "satan" can be a job title of an angel, who works for God but whose task is to tempt people and cause suffering. In particular, such a "satan" is not opposed to God. In the Hebrew, it is actually "ha-Satan", "the satan" or "the accuser" (eg in Job 1:6).

Historically, Jewish ideas about Satan changed significantly during and after the Exile, perhaps due to their exposure to Babylonian mythology. The idea that Satan is in active rebellion against God is certainly much more prevalent after this time, whatever the cause. Previously, the dominant view was against an independent adversary, and in favour of God controlling everything, good or bad.

Answer (score -3):

"Is there more than one 'Satan?'" Yes there is, and why...

The term Satan, like President, just means Leader [of Opposition], often rendered Accuser or Opponent. Jesus even called Peter (His Rock) a Satan once here:

> “Get behind me, Satan...you are not mindful of the things of God, but the things of men”. 
>   Mt. 16:22,23

Please never believe that any Satan ever works for God, the Lord outed all Satans mindsets as being ungodly [always]. The Satan of  Matthew 12:26 NKJV is a hypothetical one because you cannot have two Satans in the same rebellion. The Jews where accusing Jesus of being a Satan working for Lucifer.

> If Satan casts out Satan, he is divided against himself. How then will his kingdom stand?

The Book of Revelation says Abbaddon is a leader of a separate kingdom of evil spirits (Locusts, neither Scorpion or Serpent) who is locked in the Abyss; Lucifer is in Hades - totally different places.

> The locusts had a king over them--the angel of the bottomless pit, whose name in Hebrew is `Abaddon,'
>   Rev 9:11

The Book of Enoch explains his name as Shemjaza the Chairman of the 200 dissenters in the separate rebellion from Lucifer's. Nothing in the Bible nor Enoch proves that these 200 dissenters were part of Lucifer's rebellion.

To further complicate matters Lucifer deploys diametrical opposition to counteract the Kingdom of God. So if God is a Holy Trinity, Lucifer wants to be an Unholy Trinity:

1.Satan the Opponent = Who is in Hades.
2.Satan the Accuser - Who is in the Lower Heaven.
3.Satan the Antichrist = Who rules on Earth.

The name of the first and last Antichrist spirit is Nimrod, I cannot pin down the identity of The Accuser just yet. So..

1.Lucifer Opponent Satan.
2.Nimrod Antichrist Satan. And 
3.Abbaddon-Appolyon-Shemjazza Satan are three of four 'Satans' known to us today. But 3.Abbaddon-Appolyon-Shemjazza is not the same faction as Lucifer. As for your last question I can never accept that any of them work for God.

Comment: Where's your evidence for the locations of these spirits? Please provide verse references for all your claims.

Comment: Revelation 2:13
"I know where you live--where Satan has his throne." Antichrist
“For the accuser of the brethren who accuses them before our God day and night..” (Rev 12:10)  Accuser
Job 1:7 NIV The LORD said to Satan, "Where have you come from?" Satan answered the LORD, "From roaming through the earth and going back and forth in it." Lucifer Satan Dragon

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to put the verses and explanations into the answer itself.

Comment: -1. Please provide sources and explanations as to who or which denomination/book writes or teaches about your last four paragraphs, from *"To further complicate matters Lucifer deploys diametrical opposition to counteract the Kingdom of God. So if God is a Holy Trinity, Lucifer wants to be an Unholy Trinity"* alllll the way to *"...are three of four 'Satans' known to us today. But 3.Abbaddon-Appolyon-Shemjazza is not the same faction as Lucifer. As for your last question I can never accept that any of them work for God."* Personal opinions are not fit for this site.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. On this site, we're not looking for personal interpretation, but rather focusing on what various Christian groups teach.  See [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)